# Detect if nested array contains similar elements

Tags: ruby

I have a method that gets an array of arrays and detects if any sub array is occurs more than one time, regardless of its order:

```
def has_similar_content?(array)
  array.each.with_index do |prop1, index1|
    array.each.with_index do |prop2, index2|
      next if index1 == index2

      return true if prop1.sort == prop2.sort
    end
  end

  false
end


> has_similar_content?([%w[white xl], %w[red xl]])        
=> false

> has_similar_content?([%w[blue xl], %w[xl blue cotton]])
=> false

> has_similar_content?([%w[blue xl], %w[xl blue]])
=> true

> has_similar_content?([%w[xl green], %w[red xl], %w[green xl]])        
=> true
```

My problem is the runtime of this method, it has a quadratic complexity and needs an additional sort of the arrays to detect if the elements are the same.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Did you consider just using the [`Array#|` (intersection)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-7C) method? Or is intersect not an option because this is some kind of homework?

Comment: Is this operating exactly as you want? You don't really say so in your question. What is the expected behavior. I can somewhat infer it from your examples at the bottom but that is not a dependable way to answer your question.

Comment: Is your question the following? "Given an array `arr` of arrays, I wish to determine if there exists at least one distinct pair of elements of `arr`, `a` and `b`, such that every element of `a` is contained in `b` and every element of `b` is contained in `a`." You need something like that at the beginning of your question. "Similar" is a useless term.

Comment: Considering that you evidently have concluded that there's no need for an edit to clarify your question, please at least answer the question I asked in my comment above.

Comment: I have updated my question, I thought it would be clear

Comment: I just happened to notice your last comment. If it was intended for me you need to include my username, or part of it (e.g., @Cary) in order for me to be notified of the comment by SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way is simpler:

```
array.
  group_by(&:sort).
  transform_values(&:length).
  values.any? { |count| count > 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have assumed the question is as stated in my comment on the question.

**Code**

```
def disregarding_order_any_dups?(arr)
  arr.map do |a|
    a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |k,h|
      h[k] += 1
    end
  end.uniq.size < arr.size
end
```

**Examples**

```
disregarding_order_any_dups? [%w[white xl], %w[red xl]]
  #=> false        
disregarding_order_any_dups? [%w[blue xl],
  %w[xl blue cotton]]
  #=> false        
disregarding_order_any_dups? [%w[blue xl], %w[xl blue]]
  #=> true        
disregarding_order_any_dups? [%w[xl green], %w[red xl],
  %w[green xl]]        
  #=> true
disregarding_order_any_dups? [[1,2,3,2], [3,1,3,2],
  [2,3,1,2]]
  #=> true
```

**Complexity**

If `n = arr.size` and `m = arr.map(&:size).max`, the computational complexity is O(`n*m`). The single statement within `map`'s block could be replaced with `a.sort`, but that would increase the computational complexity to O(`n*m*log(m)`).

**Explanation**

For the last example the steps are as follows.

```
arr = [[1,2,3,2], [3,1,3,2], [2,3,1,2]]

b = arr.map do |a|
  a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |k,h|
    h[k] += 1
  end
end
  #=> [{1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>1}, {3=>2, 1=>1, 2=>1},
  #    {2=>2, 3=>1, 1=>1}] 
c = b.uniq
  #=> [{1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>1}, {3=>2, 1=>1, 2=>1}] 
d = c.size
  #=> 2 
e = arr.size
  #=> 3 
d < e
  #=> true
```

The expression

```
h = Hash.new(0)
```

creates a *counting hash*. Ruby expands `h[k] += 1` to

```
h[k] = h[k] + 1
```

The hash instance methods are `:[]=` on the left, `:[]` on the right. If `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` on the right is replaced with `h`'s *default value*, which has been defined to equal zero, resulting in:

```
h[k] = 0 + 1
```

If `h` has a key `k`, `h[k]` on the right, the value of `k`, is not replaced with `h`'s default value. See the version of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) which takes an argument equal to the hash's default value.

Answer (score 1):

This is still quadratic but it is faster :

```
def has_similar_content?(array)
  # sort subarray only once. O( n * m * log(m) )
  sorted_array= array.map(&:sort)

  # if you can change the input array, this prevent object allocation :
  # array.map!(&:sort!)

  # compare each pair only once O( n * n/2 )
  nb_elements= sorted_array.size
  0.upto(nb_elements - 1).each do |i|
    (i + 1).upto(nb_elements - 1).each do |j|
      return true if sorted_array[i] == sorted_array[j]
    end
  end
  return false
end
```